# get value on keyup event from ajax file loaded in index file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

php and getvalue.php hear getvalue.php is call through ajax.

content of Index.php are....

```
function getthis(str) {
                      var xhttp; 

                      if (str == "") {
                        document.getElementById("getthis").innerHTML = "";
                        return;
                      }
                      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                          document.getElementById("getthis").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                        }
                      };
                      xhttp.open("GET", "get.php?str="+str, true);
                      xhttp.send();
                    }
```

above script is ajax call....

and index.php content are following

```
<div id="abc">
<select name="abx" onChange="getthis(this.value)">
<option value="1" data-id="1">1</oprion>
<option value="2" data-id="2">2</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="getthis">
</div>
```

now in get value.php are following code

```
 <?php

 $_GET['str'];

 ?>

 <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['str']; ?>" class="thisis">
```

now on index.php by following scripct i want to get value from input box on keyup event by this code but i have not get any value why...?

```
<script type="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#getthis input.thisis').keyup(function(){
         var abc = $(this).val();
        alert(abc);

    });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is this something similar to suggestions like a search engine onKeyPress

Answer (score 0):

When you do this on load, the dom elements are not in there. They are being populated once the Ajax request is processed.

Instead of just trying to bind the element onload, try it once the ajax request is complete.

```js
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("getthis").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    functionbind();
}

var functionbind = function(){
    $('#getthis input.thisis').keyup(function(){
        var abc = $(this).val();
        alert(abc);

    });
    $('select ').keyup(function(){
        abc = $(this).val();
        alert(abc);

    });
}
```

Comment: i try but i can not get value please any thing else to try

Comment: Cool, Glad that I could help!